# How to use HPF client in android L or higher version with bluedroid?

Tags: android, client, hfp

I have a problem when trying to implement HFP client. Usually the android phone works as HFP ag role. But I want to make my android device work as the HF role, such as a normal headset. It seems that Google has added the HFP client code but I failed to make it. Now the A2DP works well, as it works as sink. But when I tried HFP, I can hear nothing in both side. The auto car project must finish the function i want but i cant find its source code.
   In addition, my test device is nexus 5 with android 5.0 and I can modify the rom if necessary.
   can anyone help? Just give a abc step. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems that Google's HFP client code is ok..However we need to add an audio interface to route the right voice stream. Someone has told me about this but no more details. I've seen some documents about audio policy and have no ideas. Can anyone help?

Comment: do you have any progress ?